# Logging in Eclipse-RCP "common" bundles

Tags: java, logging, log4j, eclipse-rcp

I am sure you have faced situation, when there is a project, which is a at the same time bundle and a for instance, a JAR (or other archive) which is deployed to the server. Often such projects contain persistent entities, utilities, etc., which can be used on the client and on the server.

My question is - what is the best practice to configure logging in this case? Usually, client has separate bundle with wrapped logging API. But what to do with the server and logging in this "common" project? Server might have its own configured logger - that's OK, but then "common" project will need to have also its own logger? Isn't it an overkill already? Is it a good practice at all to have logging in the "common" project?

Currently my situation is following - inside common project there is a wrapper for log4j Logger - our own Logger. It has method getLogger, which tries to configure logger, if it is not configured yet, like that:

```
private static final String LOG4J_XML_CONFIG = "log4j.xml";
    public static Logger getLogger(final String loggerName) {
        configureLogger();
        return new Logger(org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(loggerName));
    }
private static void configureLogger() {
    if (!org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders().hasMoreElements()) {
        final URL configFileResource = Logger.class.getResource(LOG4J_XML_CONFIG);
        if (configFileResource != null) {
            DOMConfigurator.configure(configFileResource);
        } else {
            org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout(PatternLayout.TTCC_CONVERSION_PATTERN)));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, basically as I understand it, in two different cases, logger should be configured differently - If request comes from client, it should log into to the client.log, if request comes from server, then into the server.log ON THE SERVER. But how can I load different configs depending on the request or may be ClassLoader?

More over, if it is a bundle, then log4.xml can't contain any references to the classes from the project it doesn't know about, like some Appenders, which are used on the server.

Edit: okay, it is actually working fine, if the "common" plugin has dependency on logging plugin (where your log4j, slf4j or whatever is bundled) and not log4j.jar! On server side it will use your lib/log4.jar. Logs from "common" plugin will appear in client.log or server.log, depending on where request comes from.

So that's the dilemma. Any help will be much appreciated.